# How use paired media query values using foundation breakpoints

Tags: zurb-foundation, breakpoint-sass

I have been using sass-breakpoint for years and you can pass in multiple values to the mixin to output a media query.
**Breakpoint Sass Example SASS**

```
div{
    @include breakpoint(500px 1000px){
        background:green;
    }
}
```

**Breakpoint Sass Example Output**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    div{
        background:green;
    }
}
```

**Foundation Breakpoint Output**
When you pass in a pair of values to the foundation breakpoint it outputs Just the contents of the breakpoint.

```
div{
   background:green;
}
```

My assumption is that the foundation breakpoint output should match the Breakpoint Sass Example Output. Instead it omits the media query all together. Ultimately, is there a way to get a min / max output using foundation's version of breakpoint?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.